# I want to make a custom ID system in sqlite in Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am currently making a stock management system in Python and I am using sqlite3 as my database. I am trying to make a custom ID system for my items that can be sold in this program.

For example I want a ID to be "IID0001". How would you do this in SQLite or would I have to write a function to work it out for me?

Comment: Are you asking how to store strings in an SQLite database?

Comment: @ScottHunter No I want to auto increment it so one item would be "IID0001" and the next would be "IID0002" when I would create the next item.

Comment: SQLite has an autoincrement field type.

Comment: @ScottHunter Isn't that only for integers tho?

Comment: If the prefix is always the same (as your question suggests), storing an integer would be sufficient.  If it isn't, you'll have to explain your additional requirements.

Comment: @ScottHunter well I am using it as my primary key for this table but I am using it in a  different table. I was also going to use a similar thing on a different table but same concept, but this time it would be a customer id "CID..." but I was going to use it as apart of a composite key in a different table.

Comment: It still seems unnecessary to store the prefix, but if you insist, @mkrieger1 points you to how to do that, although it won't be the primary key & still needs an autoincrement field.